# How to create a text sticker view in swift, like in Canva App, which is resizable as per the text content in it

Tags: swift, view, uikit, sticker

How to create a text sticker view in swift, like in Canva App, which is resizable as per the text content in it.

App link :- https://www.canva.com/

Expecting to create a text sticker view in swift, when we reduce it's width then it's height should  increase as per the content in it.

Comment: Please review [ask]. To get help, take the time to write a question that ***clearly explains*** what you're asking. You should not expect people to go look at some other application and try to guess what you're talking about.